# Does increments (++i/i++) work differently in windows than linux?

Tags: c

I am having some trouble figuring out why this code is showing different results in linux and windows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=2;
    x = 4 * x++;
    printf("%d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

In linux it is showing `8` (which is logically correct I think). In windows it is showing `9`. Is it because the increment is done *after* the statement is finished executed rather than when evaluating? The same thing happens for pre-increments.

NB: In linux I am using gcc, in windows I am using mingw (codeblocks).

Comment: I tried with gcc version 4.7.2 under linux (Debian 4.7.2-5). It returns 9, not 8.

Comment: Because different devs have different considerations when implementing **defined behaviours**, resulting in different **undefined** ones.

Comment: Actually, the undefined behaviour is detected by the -Wall option of the  gcc compiler

Comment: So that's the reason. And may be it is the newer gcc (mine is 4.9.3) that the behaviour is changed, not because of the OS. :|

Comment: And I didn't know that it is an undefined behaviour. Thanks @MichelBillaud